# Is my Windows 10 installation reusing the system and recovery partitions of other installation?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd, disk-management, recovery

In my desktop PC I have an SSD where I installed Windows 10 many years ago. Later I purchased an nvme ssd, where I also installed Windows 10, and I can choose which Windows 10 to launch at boot. Both disks are using MBR, not GPT.

Fast forward to now, I want to remove my SSD and just keep the nvme. I launch Disk Management and I can see the SSD (that I want to remove) with the three typical partitions: system, main and recovery. But the nvme only has one partition, the main partition, taking the full disk size. It's labeled as "Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition) "

[image]

I've tried unplugging the SSD (disk 0 in the image) and the system does not boot, apparently because it's missing the system partition. How can I add (or move) a system partition to the nvme (disk 3 in the image)?

Comment: “So my question is, will I have issues if I remove the SSD given that the nvme does not have any kind of system or recovery partitions?” - You don’t really clarify which disk your going to remove, if it’s the disk with your boot partition, the install on the other disk obviously won’t boot. Screenshots are helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound I've added an image and clarified the situation after trying with the the original disk unplugged. Effectively, the system does not boot, so I need to add a system partition to the nvme.

Comment: Create a partition at the begiing of the disk and clone the system partition to that partition